# JQuery Using toggleClass() inside a .click() of the same class doesn't seem to work

Tags: jquery, html, click, toggleclass

So what I'm trying to do is sort of like the thumbs up/thumbs down voting system on youtube using jquery, implying that once a user has voted, both divs(images, doesn't matter what) will become unavailable for that specific post.

So far, to do so, I use a .click() inside which a toggleClass() will change its own class, I can see that the class changes if I inspect the DOM, but why is the .click() still working on the new class ?

```
//TO BE CALLED WHEN USER CLICKS VOTE FORGIVENESS
$('.voteUp').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).closest("article").attr("id");

    //Make it impossible to vote again
    $(this).toggleClass('voteUp votedUp');
    $(this).parent().find('.voteDown').toggleClass('voteDown votedDown');

});
```

And my html (php)

```
        <article class='yellowSheet' id='57'>
            <div class="title">
                <h1>StuffUp says :</h1>
                <p class="story">What happened ?</p>
            </div>

            <div class="entryContent">
                <p>guy, 2011-06-28 17:11:48</p>
            </div>

            <div class="voting">
                <img class="voteUp" src="images/thumbsUp.png" /></div>
                <img class="voteDown" src="images/thumbsDown.png" /></div>
            <div class="storyBottom"></div>

        </article>
```

What I don't understand is why after toggling class, I still can click on the new class-"votedDown" since that class doesn't have a .click method ?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class name is only the means you use to match an element: the `click` handler is registered on the element itself and will be called whether it still exposes the class or not.

You can use [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) to register an event handler that will only be called if the element still matches the initial selector:

```
$(".voteUp").live("click", function() {
    // Your event handler.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already bound a click event to the object.  You cannot remove the class an expect the click event to come with it.  What you want is to call this:

```
$(this).unbind('click');
```

Answer (score 0):

I would actually remove the voteUp and add votedUp.

```
$(this).removeClass('voteUp').addClass('votedUp');
```

If you want to toggle a class, possibly just toggle 'votedUp', not 'voteUp votedUp'. If you have a click event assigned to 'voteUp', simply adding on 'votedUp' in your toggle won't remove that click bind.

Answer (score 0):

.click binds an event handler to all the entities that match your selector at 'run time' - so despite removing the class, the entity still has a click event bound.

You can do one of two things. Either use:

```
$('.voteUp').live('click', function() { 
    // etc 
} );
```

'live' behaves in the manner that you are expecting 'click' to, and only activates when you click on something that matches its selector - and it analyses this every time you click.

Or you can unbind the event manually in the event handler, eg:

```
$('.voteUp').bind('click.voteUp', function(e) { 
    $(this).unbind('click.voteUp'); 
   // and the rest of what you want to do; 
});
```

This second example also uses namespaced event handlers, a neat feature in jquery, which means only your named event handler will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

It actually binds to the element and not the class.  The class name is just used for the initial lookup.

In this case you would either want to use the `.unbind()` method to unbind the click event after it's been clicked `$(this).unbind('click');`

OR

use the `.one()` [method](http://api.jquery.com/one/) which would only allow the element to be clicked once.

```
$('.voteUp').one('click', function() {...
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it matters at this point, but you have an extra "`</div>`", I reformatted what you have to make the issue clearer:

```
<div class="voting">
    <img class="voteUp" src="images/thumbsUp.png" />
</div> <!-- Extra close div -->
    <img class="voteDown" src="images/thumbsDown.png" />
</div>
```

So I don't think the find() in this statement is going to match anything:

```
 $(this).parent().find('.voteDown').toggleClass('voteDown votedDown');
```